# Can selenium be used to highlight sections of a web page?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, highlighting

Can I have any highlight kind of things using Python 2.7? Say when my script clicking on the `submit button`,feeding data into the `text field` or selecting values from the `drop-down field`, just to highlight on that element to make sure to the script runner that his/her script doing what he/she wants.

***EDIT***

I am using selenium-webdriver with python to automate some web based work on a third party application.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the framework you are using for your website.

Comment: I am talking about webpage automation. it is doing the things perfectly, but not viable where it is clicking,I just want to see that if Python have that functionality.

Comment: Web pages are built from HTML, CSS and JavaScript - where is Python involved?

Comment: Python i am using to do web-automation using `selenium - webdriver`

Comment: That is incredibly important information that you should include in your question.

Comment: Your question should be: Can selenium be used to highlight sections of a web page?  The fact you are controlling selenium with Python is largely irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't get the answer for which i gave this post!

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do it. Selenium is used to run tests (usually in an unattended manner) which means making changes to the site you are testing/automating is out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

This is something you need to do with javascript, not python.

Comment: There is no way in `Python` to do so?

Comment: Python does not run in the client browser.

Comment: Turns out he is using selenium (from Python) to control a browser session with another website.

Answer (score 1):

***[NOTE: I'm leaving this answer for historical purposes but readers should note that the original question has changed from concerning itself with Python to concerning itself with Selenium]***

Assuming you're talking about a browser based application being served from a Python back-end server (and it's just a guess since there's *no information* in your post):

If you are constructing a response in your Python back-end, wrap the stuff that you want to highlight in a `<span>` tag and set a `class` on the span tag.  Then, in your CSS define that class with whatever highlighting properties you want to use.

However, if you want to accomplish this highlighting in an already-loaded browser page without generating new HTML on the back end and returning that to the browser, then Python (on the server) has no knowledge of or ability to affect the web page in browser.  You must accomplish this using Javascript or a Javascript library or framework in the browser.

Comment: Turns out he is using selenium to control a browser session with another website.

Comment: Indeed.  Kind of makes a difference, doesn't it?